# Tex capacity exceeded-- \clearpage wont help

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

When fed with more than 6 blocks of the form below (and nothing but that, except for begindocument and , Latex responds with capacity exceeded error.

```
\paragraph{Length 5}
-
\begin{figure}[H] 
\centering \newlength\figureheight \newlength\figurewidth \setlength\figureheight{6cm} \setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
\input{../dat/l5s1000.dat} 
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Length 5, no bdy}
-
\begin{figure}[H] 
\centering  \setlength\figureheight{6cm} \setlength\figurewidth{6cm} \setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
\input{../dat/nobdyl5s1000.dat} 
\end{figure}

\clearpage
```

The head of my document currently looks like

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
```

I figure the reason is the [H] that I am forcing on Latex, but I don't know how else to get Latex to really put the figures on the page I want it on. Without it, what I normally end up with is a few paragraph headings in a row, then a few figures, then a few paragraph headings. Also I thought \clearpage would exactly get rid of the problem occurring with the use of [H]

EDIT:
the .dat files look like this:

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.95092\figurewidth,
height=0.418605\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0.581395\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0.001,
xmax=1,
xmajorgrids,
ymode=log,
ymin=1e-07,
ymax=0.001,
ytick={ 1e-07,  1e-06,  1e-05, 0.0001,  0.001},
yminorticks=true,
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   1.01474910759058\\
0.999   1.01474910759058\\
0.998   1.01474910759058\\
0.997   1.01474910759058\\
0.996   1.01474910759058\\
0.995   1.01474910759058\\
0.994   1.01474910759058\\
0.993   1.01474910759058\\
0.992   1.01474910759058\\
0.991   1.01474910759058\\
0.99    1.01474910759058\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

only they contain much more numbers (1000, to be exact). Taking the figures out of the figure environment is a smart idea once I realized the .dats were just code. However, the figures then still dont come where they should--after the text they were put and before the text that comes afterwards

Comment: If you don't want it to float, don't put it in a `figure` environment.

Comment: You haven't really given any information about why your memory use is high. You can simply remove the `\begin{figure}` `\end{figure}` lines they are not doing anything useful, but are not a source of memory problems. Presumably whatever unshown code is in your input `.dat` files is using up a lot of memory but since we have no information hard to say. You could try lualatex which uses dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: thanks for the comments. the .dat files I created with matlab2tikz, I wasn't aware they contained regular latex code, I will edit my post

Comment: Do you mind posting this as a single code post? Much easier for the rest of us to download and test.